# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-batch, hibernate-4.x

For some reason I get the following exception when using Spring Batch in combination with Hibernate 4.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemReaderHelper.createQuery(HibernateItemReaderHelper.java:152)
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemReaderHelper.getForwardOnlyCursor(HibernateItemReaderHelper.java:122)
at ....
```

I upgraded to the latest Spring batch 2.1.8.RELEASE and Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE which supposed to work with Hibernate 4. I looked into the source and it seems that the helper class is using the new version of the session factory that is used in Hibernate 4:

```
package org.springframework.batch.item.database;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.ScrollMode;
import org.hibernate.ScrollableResults;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.StatelessSession;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.orm.HibernateQueryProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

/**
 * Internal shared state helper for hibernate readers managing sessions and
 * queries.
 * 
 * @author Dave Syer
 * 
 */
public class HibernateItemReaderHelper<T> implements InitializingBean {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private String queryString = "";

    private String queryName = "";

    private HibernateQueryProvider queryProvider;

    private boolean useStatelessSession = true;

    private StatelessSession statelessSession;

    private Session statefulSession;

    /**
     * @param queryName name of a hibernate named query
     */
    public void setQueryName(String queryName) {
        this.queryName = queryName;
    }

    /**
     * @param queryString HQL query string
     */
    public void setQueryString(String queryString) {
        this.queryString = queryString;
    }

    /**
     * @param queryProvider Hibernate query provider
     */
    public void setQueryProvider(HibernateQueryProvider queryProvider) {
        this.queryProvider = queryProvider;
    }

    /**
     * Can be set only in uninitialized state.
     * 
     * @param useStatelessSession <code>true</code> to use
     * {@link StatelessSession} <code>false</code> to use standard hibernate
     * {@link Session}
     */
    public void setUseStatelessSession(boolean useStatelessSession) {
        Assert.state(statefulSession == null && statelessSession == null,
                "The useStatelessSession flag can only be set before a session is initialized.");
        this.useStatelessSession = useStatelessSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param sessionFactory hibernate session factory
     */
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        Assert.state(sessionFactory != null, "A SessionFactory must be provided");

        if (queryProvider == null) {
            Assert.notNull(sessionFactory, "session factory must be set");
            Assert.state(StringUtils.hasText(queryString) ^ StringUtils.hasText(queryName),
                    "queryString or queryName must be set");
        }
        // making sure that the appropriate (Hibernate) query provider is set
        else {
            Assert.state(queryProvider != null, "Hibernate query provider must be set");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Get a cursor over all of the results, with the forward-only flag set.
     * 
     * @param fetchSize the fetch size to use retrieving the results
     * @param parameterValues the parameter values to use (or null if none).
     * 
     * @return a forward-only {@link ScrollableResults}
     */
    public ScrollableResults getForwardOnlyCursor(int fetchSize, Map<String, Object> parameterValues) {
        Query query = createQuery();
        if (parameterValues != null) {
            query.setProperties(parameterValues);
        }
        return query.setFetchSize(fetchSize).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
    }

    /**
     * Open appropriate type of hibernate session and create the query.
     */
    public Query createQuery() {

        if (useStatelessSession) {
            if (statelessSession == null) {
                statelessSession = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
            }
            if (queryProvider != null) {
                queryProvider.setStatelessSession(statelessSession);
            }
            else {
                if (StringUtils.hasText(queryName)) {
                    return statelessSession.getNamedQuery(queryName);
                }
                else {
                    return statelessSession.createQuery(queryString);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (statefulSession == null) {
                statefulSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
            }
            if (queryProvider != null) {
                queryProvider.setSession(statefulSession);
            }
            else {
                if (StringUtils.hasText(queryName)) {
                    return statefulSession.getNamedQuery(queryName);
                }
                else {
                    return statefulSession.createQuery(queryString);
                }
            }
        }

        // If queryProvider is set use it to create a query
        return queryProvider.createQuery();

    }

    /**
     * Scroll through the results up to the item specified.
     * 
     * @param cursor the results to scroll over
     */
    public void jumpToItem(ScrollableResults cursor, int itemIndex, int flushInterval) {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemIndex; i++) {
            cursor.next();
            if (i % flushInterval == 0 && !useStatelessSession) {
                statefulSession.clear(); // Clears in-memory cache
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the open session (stateful or otherwise).
     */
    public void close() {
        if (statelessSession != null) {
            statelessSession.close();
            statelessSession = null;
        }
        if (statefulSession != null) {
            statefulSession.close();
            statefulSession = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read a page of data, clearing the existing session (if necessary) first,
     * and creating a new session before executing the query.
     * 
     * @param page the page to read (starting at 0)
     * @param pageSize the size of the page or maximum number of items to read
     * @param fetchSize the fetch size to use
     * @param parameterValues the parameter values to use (if any, otherwise
     * null)
     * @return a collection of items
     */
    public Collection<? extends T> readPage(int page, int pageSize, int fetchSize, Map<String, Object> parameterValues) {

        clear();

        Query query = createQuery();
        if (parameterValues != null) {
            query.setProperties(parameterValues);
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<T> result = query.setFetchSize(fetchSize).setFirstResult(page * pageSize).setMaxResults(pageSize).list();
        return result;

    }

    /**
     * Clear the session if stateful.
     */
    public void clear() {
        if (statefulSession != null) {
            statefulSession.clear();
        }
    }

}
```

So the question is why is it still trying to use an older version even though the newest is used. Does anybody have an idea why this still could be happening?

Comment: Check your classpath for duplicated jars in different versions.

Comment: share your pom.xml or list of jars

Comment: That's what I already did and as far as I can see there is only 1 jar that includes this class which is the spring-batch-infrastructure JAR file. Do you have any suggestions/tools to check the classpath? Now I just checked the within Eclipse in which jar this file resides and it only pops up in one jar which contains the correct version.

Comment: It's a webapp? This can occur if your web container (eg. tomcat) have another version of the jars.

Comment: It is a webapp indeed but as far as I can see there are no JARS that include the HibernateItemReaderHelper class. As far as I know this only resides in spring-batch-infrastructure.jar. I only see one in my WAR and none in my Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally got it to work by compiling Spring batch against Hibernate 4. It seems Spring batch is not compatible with Hibernate 4.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's in my WAR:

```
activation-1.1.jar
amqp-client-2.7.1.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
aspectjrt-1.5.0.jar
aspectjweaver-1.5.2.jar
aspectjweaver-1.6.9.jar
avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar
billing-commons-1.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
billing-core-1.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar
classpath.txt
commons-batch-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-cli-1.1.jar
commons-codec-1.2.jar
commons-customer-experience-1.3.0.jar
commons-domain-1.0.0.jar
commons-email-1.1.jar
commons-email-1.9.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
commons-hibernate-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
commons-http-1.2.1.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-httpclient-contrib-3.1.jar
commons-io-1.3.1.jar
commons-lang-2.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.2.0.jar
commons-monitoring-1.0.0.jar
commons-property-3.3.0.jar
commons-rabbitmq-1.1.1.jar
commons-spring-agent-2.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
commons-util-1.6.1.jar
customer-inventory-commons-1.4.0.jar
customer-inventory-core-1.4.0.jar
cxf-api-2.3.2.jar
cxf-common-schemas-2.3.2.jar
cxf-common-utilities-2.3.2.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.3.2.jar
cxf-rt-core-2.3.2.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.3.2.jar
cxf-rt-transports-common-2.3.2.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-2.3.2.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
generic-monitoring-console-api-1.1.0.jar
geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.4.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jettison-1.1.jar
jms-1.1.jar
jsr250-api-1.0.jar
jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
logkit-1.0.1.jar
mail-1.4.jar
neethi-2.0.4.jar
orchestration-api-1.7.0-20120820.120350-6.jar
quartz-1.5.2.jar
simplestuff-0.9.jar
singleview-api-commons-1.1.0.jar
singleview-api-core-1.1.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
slf4j-simple-1.5.6.jar
spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-core-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-infrastructure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
stax2-api-3.0.2.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
woodstox-core-asl-4.0.8.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
xstream-1.3.1.jar
```